# Excel - VLookup Example

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am writing a simple list of equities for the various two playing card combinations against a certain range of an opponent.

My column A is the first card (A, 2, 3, ..., K), the column B is the second card (A, 2, 3, ..., K) and the column C will only contain one letter (`s`), or be blank, to indicate whether these two cards are suited or not.

Every possible combination (169 in total) has its own Expected Value (column D, %).

On another sheet I am trying to type a cards combination in three cells and get the corresponding EV number appear in the next cell.

So far I have tried the following:

I created the additional column (E) and inserted and dragged the formula:

```
=&A1&B1&C1
```

I did the same for the second sheet input, so when I type (in separate cells) Q, J, s the reference cell would show `QJs`.

Finally, I use the VLookup to find the resulted QJs on the Sheet1, column E and return the corresponding data of the column D to the Sheet2, but cannot get the answer. I have tried to search for the help but seems like I miss some syntax-related accuracy, could someone see where have I gone wrong, please?

My formula on Sheet2 looks like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(D1,Sheet1!E:E,Sheet1!D:D,)
```

Comment: The second parameter should define the entire array (including search and result columns).  The search column is automatically the leftmost column. The third parameter is the index number of the column in the array that the result should come from.  If you can't make the search column the left one, use INDEX +MATCH instead, as in Scott's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VLOOKUP` is designed so that the data that you want to get
must be in a column to the right of the column that you are matching. 
(IMNSHO, this is a design flaw.)  Try:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!D:D, MATCH(D1, Sheet1!E:E, 0), 1)
```

Or you can redesign your `Sheet1` so that your `A1&B1&C1` column
is to the left of your Expected Value column.

Comment: Appreciate your help, again. I don't have the access to the real Excel till Monday to check the VLookup column shift, so far I tried on Ipad's Numbers and your INDEX+MATCH worked perfectly, however changing the columns didn't get much change in the VLookup option. Let me try on real Excel on Monday too. Since I am not (yet) fluent with Index and Match combinations, I may need to use VLookup for the time being.

Comment: I managed to make it work with VLookup too on Excel, many thanks!